# Transportation during short visit to London

Tags: public-transport, tickets, london

From Egypt, I am visiting London for two days and am concerned about transportation:

What are my public transportation options from Gatwick Airport to Chiswell Street and vice versa?

edit : it would be better to use over ground transport (buses for example) .

Comment: Please split this into two questions.

Comment: I have edited your question to focus on the first of your two questions. Please ask a separate question to ask about communications.

Comment: You can use Google Maps to answer this question easily and accurately.

Comment: I did , but I have read that visitors cannot use some public transport except with oyster card

Comment: Who told you that you cannot use Oyster card on public transports ? There are certain restrictions, like while using a taxi(you cannot use Oyster on taxi) or getting out of certain zones. And one golden rule in London, if you want to reach quickly use underground, but not always

Comment: I have been told  that  Gatewick air port is outside the valid  zone for Oyster card

Comment: Gatwick is outside the oyster zone.  At Gatwick you can purchace a ticket that includes the underground, you only require zone one for the tube journey to Moorgate or Barbican.  If you are travelling in London other than your journey to and from Gatwick, then once you get to London you can purchace an Oyster card at most tube stations and travel shops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that the Chiswell street is the one in central London. With a postcode of EC1Y 4SA or similar

The best option would be the Thameslink rail service from Gatwick to Farringdon station, and then transfer to the underground for a short journey to Moorgate or Barbican, depending on which end of the street you want. There will then be a 3 or 4 min walk.

You can get timetable information here, and the line you are looking for is the Brighton Bedford route.

[ThamesLink](http://www.thameslinkrailway.com)

Then this link gives an idea of the locality (it references a restaurant but you'll get the idea)

[London Town](http://www.londontown.com/TransportInformation/Dining/Chiswell-Street-Dining-Rooms/17714/)